# Why RxJava with Retrofit on Android doOnError() does not work but Subscriber onError does

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android, subscriber

can someone explain me why code like this:

```
 networApi.getList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
                throwable.getMessage();
            })
            .doOnNext(list -> {
                coursesView.populateRecyclerView(list);
                courseList = (List<Course>) courses;
            }).subscribe();
```

If there is no internet goes into doOnError but throws it further so the app goes down, but code like this:

```
networkApi.getList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<? extends Course>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<? extends Course> list) {
                    coursesView.populateRecyclerView(list);
                    courseList = (List<Course>) list;
                }
            });
```

Work how I expect, it means when there is no internet connection it does nothing.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Basically, `doOnError` does not *handle* the error, in the sense that it does not *consume* it. It just *does something with it*, log it, for example. (The same is true for `doOnNext` - it also does not consume the item and the item still ends up in `onNext` of the `Subscriber`).

The error is still sent down the chain and would still end up in the `onError` of your `Subscriber`.

I am pretty certain that your app is crashing with an `OnErrorNotImplementedException` and that is because you don't have any `Subscriber` at all and therefore no `onError` method.

Comment: @david.mihola is there a way to handle HTTP status codes onError with retrofit beta 2  ?

Comment: Yeah it works, but why? it is not clear for me why doOnError doesn't work. can you give an example of a good usage of doOnError?

Comment: @JhonFredyTrujilloOrtega: Other than logging, not really. It's tempting to use it for UI updates (hide progress indicator when a network request emits `onError`), but see Jake Wharton's talk http://jakewharton.com/the-state-of-managing-state-with-rxjava/ for a cleaner alternative that doesn't use `doOn*` methods.