# RxBus.Publish() throws OnErrorNotImplementedException

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am using `RxBus`for event passing from adapter class to fragment for specific subject

```
RxBus.publish(RxBus.SUBJECT_DELETE_SCHEME_FROM_CART, option)
```

and subscribe code is

```
RxBus.subscribe(RxBus.SUBJECT_DELETE_SCHEME_FROM_CART, this, Consumer {
        if (it is GeneratedPortfolioResponse.GeneratedPortfolioScheme) {
              // code
        })
```

when I publish any event from adapter class it throws OnErrorNotImplementedException.

How can I handle this?

Comment: Could you show how you subscribe to the stream?

Comment: @tynn I have edit question, please have a look

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520107/how-to-handle-onerror-inside-rxjava-i-am-getting-onerrornotimplementedexceptio/34520290)?

Comment: @Piyush yes. Not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
   RxBus.subscribe(result ->  if (result is GeneratedPortfolioResponse.GeneratedPortfolioScheme) 
     {
          // code
     }, error -> yourshowErrorMethod(error))
```